# Adding ssd to boost drive space

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, ssd, desktop

Simple question. I already own an SSD and I want to get more space on my computer. If I buy another solid state drive and install it, will it effectively add more space?

Example: I have used up all of my space on my current SSD and would like to install more games without drastically cleaning my other SSD. Can I just buy another SSD and gain more space or will I have to buy a bigger SSD and reinstall everything to gain a boost in drive space?

Thanks!

Comment: I would just buy a bigger SSD and migrate everything to that. They are really inexpensive these days.The other solutions that were proposed are possible but much more finagle.

Comment: You can do both. However if you get a second SSD and decide to use both simultaneously you will have to change the destination where you are installing games by default and downloading stuff. Ax you cannot extend the existing partition across two drives without reinstalling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to migrate some data to the new SSD to free up space on the old one.  Simply plugging in a second drive will just give you another drive letter; it will not "extend" the SSD you already have.

You can create "spanned" volumes with multiple SSDs, but you can't boot off them.  So if your OS is installed to your current SSD, that option is off the table.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you'll get more space. But it'll be in a different drive letter. But it's possible to direct program installations into the 2nd SSD as well. Some of the program's data (depending on the program) might still need to be kept on the 1st SSD where your OS is installed, so you might still want to clean it up a bit.

If you can connect your second SSD your computer via SATA, it would act almost identical to your current one (assuming SSD speeds are similar).

If the 2nd SSD is going to be connected via a external port like USB, it'll be slower. You'll also have to keep it permanently attached. But otherwise, it'll work fine.

If you want to, you can raid 0 the 2 SSDs together to get a single volume, but it'll expose you to higher risk of hard drive failure. (You'll probably need to move all the data on the first SSD elsewhere first though.)